# Excel read fails

Tags: excel, python-2.7, com

Excel read fails when I keep the dispatch and open Workbook methods outside the Rdxcel_MVP function,called from external Python modules. (But works fine when I keep it inside the function.)
But I wanted to keep these statements out of function. How I make these statements global..

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible= True
excelApl= excel.Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Flexray_Models\AutomationDesk\Third_party_IF\Model_Variable_Path.xlsx")

def Rdxcel_MVP(Item_MainRow_idx):
    
   try:

        ls_MV_path =[]

        xcell_idx = ['A','B','C']

        str_concact = str(xcell_idx[0]) + str(Item_MainRow_idx);
        print ls_MV_path
        ls_MV_path.append(excelApl.Worksheets("FRM_ENBS").Range(str_concact).Value)
    
        print ls_MV_path
        return ls_MV_path
   except:
        print "Excel Read Failed"
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show the code that calls `Rdxcel_MVP()`? Is the function being called from a different thread?

Comment: Error is.. "Excel Read Failed"..  Unfortnately couldnt show the other code.. But the call works fine when I keep the dispatch and other init methods inside the Rdxcel_MVP

Comment: Remove the try/except handling and see what exception is being raised.